# The variation in efficiency of hydraulic machines

Tags: fluid-mechanics

Why does the efficiency of all hydraulic machines increase initially with increase in discharge and then decrease on further increase in discharge?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the limiting cases, as follows. the limit of the low flow condition is blocked flow, where the pump is churning the fluid up to maximum pressure but no work is being done on the load because there is **zero flow**. Efficiency will be low in this case. The limit of the high flow condition is the no-load state, where the pump is moving the fluid at maximum flow rate but no useful work is performed because **no pressure** is being applied to any load. Efficiency tends to zero in this case too. Between these cases, **both** fluid flow rate **and** pressure are simultaneously nonzero and the efficiency will go through a maximum.